FluentAvaloniaUI NavigationItem Icon
I'm developing a software in C# using Avalonia (It's the first time I've used it and I still have some difficulty).
I added the FluentAvaloniaUI nuget package for the controls and LucideAvalonia for the icons.
navigationview binding works perfectly
<ui:NavigationView MenuItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ui:NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:MainMenuItem">
            <ui:NavigationViewItem Content="{Binding Title}" IconSource="{Binding Icon}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ui:NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
</ui:NavigationView>

this is the MainMenuItem model (I have an observable list in the viewmodel initialized in the constructor)
i would like to change the Icon type from string to LucideIconNames (Lucide icons enumerator)
public class MainMenuItem 
{
    public string Title { get; init; }
    public string Icon { get; init; }
    public Control View { get; init; }
}

but I'm not crazy about icons, so I would like to use the LucideAvalonia icons.
however the icon control of the NavigationViewItem is FluentAvalonia.UI.Controls.IconSource and I have difficulty changing it.
This is what i tryied in the UserControl.Styles, but obviously it doesn't work
<Style Selector="uip|NavigationViewItemPresenter /template/ ContentPresenter#Icon">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Template>
            <lucideAvalonia:Lucide Icon="House" StrokeBrush="SaddleBrown" />
        </Template>
    </Setter>
</Style>

Can anyone help me? even just with some hints.

The Lucide object is just a user control that wraps a DrawingImage.  In this case I would avoid using this user control.  Instead, import the raw ResourceDictionary from Lucide into your project which has the DrawingImages.  DrawingImage implements IImage, and the FluentAvalonia IconSource appears to have a built-in type converter for that, so you can use them directly.
